# What is the font used in this screenshot from Microsoft Office?

Tags: fonts

Can someone please tell me what font/fonts Microsoft is using in this screenshot? I have tried several of the online resources supplied in the guidelines about identifying fonts, but the results are definitely not correct. I am not a designer, so I really don't have a clue.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to follow our [font identification guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366). Otherwise your question is likely to get closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segoe UI.

[image]

The red is Segoe UI for sure, typed directly above a screen shot of the menu. As you can see, they are VERY  close, if not the exact same.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed Segoe UI, as God is good answered.
This is the main font used by Microsoft since Windows 8 was anounced in 2012.

If you want to discover fonts names from screenshots, you may want to use one of the following sites.

http://www.whatfontis.com/

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

You can upload an image just like the one you used in your question and they will return you the font name most of the time.

Comment: Both recognizers give ridiculous results. Luckily there's this site, even though the community chose to denigrate the question's poster.